# will fb:name stop working completely?

Tags: facebook, fbml

I see that fbml will stop working on 6'th of June 2012. So I assume these are the tags like fb:name and so on.

Is fb:name also xfbml and will xbml also stop working?

How else can I display a non auth'ed user his own name?

I tried the following but for this I need an access token, so it is of no use:
http://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it will stop working, not sure when (they sometimes change their mind about dates) but you should stop using it. What exactly do you want with the user's name if he's not authorized?

Comment: We have an app with which users can create content and many of them have some text : "Hello <fb:name uid="loggedinuser"></fb:name>
So it is purely for personalizing the content a bit..

Comment: I don't think that you can find an alternative with the graph api, you  probably should just write "click here to sign in" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

`XFBML` is not the same as `FBML`, and only the latter has been deprecated, so `fb:name` will continue working.